# Rails tutorial 3.6, 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm stuck at section 3.6 of railstutorial.org, specifically when I run

```
> bin/rspec spec/
```

on my Windows 7 machine I get 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have already typed

```
> bundle --binstubs
```

I don't have RVM on here. Should I install it?

When I go cd bin and execute rspec, I get

```
'load': cannot load such file
```

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd reiterate the author's warning about this section:

> "This section should only be attempted by fairly advanced users and
>   can be skipped without loss of continuity. Among other things, this
>   material is likely to go out of date faster than the rest of the
>   tutorial, so you shouldn’t expect everything on your system to match
>   the examples exactly, and you may have to Google around to get
>   everything to work."

As a side note... I originally tried to use ruby on rails on a windows machine but I found that much of the support community used apple or linux boxes.  I have been much happier since I started dual-booting into Ubuntu.  The transition was easier than I expected and I have had fewer issues with gems.

Comment: Yup, I put it on the side for now... probably going to try it again in the future once I reread the book.