# bin/rails giving error that 'bin' is not recognized as internal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, bin

I am a beginner trying to learn and do the Ruby on Rails tutorials (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails)

and for all the bin commands in the command window such as 
    $ bin/rails --version 
or
    $ bin/rails server

I am getting the error " 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

I just installed the latest version of Ruby so I've tried running
    rake rails:update:bin

and I also added the PATH variable C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin to my environment variables.

I'm still getting the same error.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails tutorial 3.6, 'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241372/rails-tutorial-3-6-bin-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 6):

You are getting those errors because you are on Windows. In this case you have to pass the scripts under the `bin` folder directly to the Ruby interpreter like this:

```
ruby bin\rails server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the `bin` directory to your `PATH` variable, then you don't need to use it in the command. Just type `$ rails --version`, etc.